# How to connect 2 Macs via SSH on a home network?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

First off, I'm not 100% sure this question is on-topic on StackOverflow, but here you go :

I've set up a home network :

- 1 wireless router connected to the internet
- my 2 Macs connected to the wireless router

Is there any way I could use **SSH** to connect from my `Mac No 1` to my `Mac No 2`?

And How?

Comment: System Preferences > Sharing, check Remote Login

Comment: It's off-topic (although arguably "developer tools"), but at least it is a well-enough written question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

First, go to System Preferences -> Sharing.  Turn on *Remote Login* (see image).

Then, from a terminal, execute:

```
$ ssh <machine name>.local
```

[image: Remote Login]

Comment: Well, what do you mean by Machine name? The computer name of the receiver? I tried that and i'm getting a `ssh: Could not resolve hostname drkMBPro: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: just fixed it by using `drkMBPro.local` as my Machine name... That was quite easy; I'm still quite new to Macs... so... Thanks a lot, buddy! :-)

Comment: Of the *receiver* yes. When you turned on sharing on that machine, what did it report (see in the graphic it says: "To log in to this computer remotely, type 'ssh greg@zaphod'").

Comment: Yep, that last one works too. ;-)

Comment: And to login as a specific user: `ssh username@machineName.local`. You will be prompted for the password for the chosen user.